# How to fetch recruiter report by linkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to create service to collect all reporting data for all recruiters from my organization.
That will be APIs from this group https://www.linkedin.com/talent/reporting/api/. I checked all public documentation for linkedIn APIs but I didn't find any of these ones.

Example of inspect network call: https://www.linkedin.com/talent/reporting/api/talentActivityReportFilterSuggestions?filterTypes=List(JOB_FUNCTION,LOCATION,USER_GEO_LOCATION,OWNER,HIRE_GROUP,PROJECT,TITLE,SPONSORED_CAMPAIGN,HIRING_MANAGER,SENIORITY,ROLE_TYPE)&q=suggestionTypes&query=(hiringProjectTypes:List(RECRUITER,JOB_POSTING))

I tried to call these from postman, but I got status '403' with msg 'CSRF check failed'.
It required some cookies, but that is not solution for my case. I need documentation for this group of APIs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is CSRF check failed when going on a website which doesn't require login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57048799/what-is-csrf-check-failed-when-going-on-a-website-which-doesnt-require-login)

Comment: No, I need documentation for these APIs. This answer explained that I miss cookies when I run by postman, I know that.